# Laravel Bulk Update for multiple record ids

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I want to mass update my records in Laravel but the records not getting updated. I have a different record for each Id. Below is what I am trying.

```
$ids = [5,6,8,9],
$updated_array = [
  ['name' => 'tarun'],
  ['name' => 'Akash'],
  ['name' => 'Soniya'],
  ['name' => 'Shalu'],
];

Model::whereIn('id', $ids)->update($updated_array);
```

Comment: in your model, set `protected $guarded = array();`
`$fillable` and `$guarded` properties are used to enable mass insertion and updates

Answer (score 17):

Mass updates are used when you're trying to update multiple rows to the same values.  You cannot mass update with different values.

Therefore, this would work, but would update all matching records to name of 'tarun':

```
Model::whereIn('id', $ids)->update(['name' => 'tarun']);
```

For your example, you could do:

```
foreach($ids as $key => $id) {
    Model::where('id', $id)->update($updated_array[$key]);
}
```

But as far as I know, there's no way to do this without running 4 queries in Laravel and writing a raw SQL statement to accomplish this would even be messy.

Comment: i does not want to run foreach loop.

Comment: Why not?  Seems pointless to make this harder than it is, it's a simple loop.

Comment: if there are 10000 records then there will executed 10000. Does it make any sense to execute 10000 queries for a simple operation

Comment: If they are all different queries, then yes.  You're not updating it with the same values...

Answer (score 10):

You can use [Laravel Upsert](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#upserts) for mass update.
For example :

```
User::query()->upsert([
    ['id' => 1, 'email' => 'dadan@example.com'],
    ['id' => 2, 'email' => 'satria@example.com'],
], 'email');
```

This feature available in Laravel 8 or newer

Answer (score 4):

Some good solutions for this issue are on the following post: https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/575

1) Can create  custom function to do this, which uses raw SQL, as per barryvdh comment in the post.

```
    public static function updateValues(array $values)
    {
        $table = MyModel::getModel()->getTable();

        $cases = [];
        $ids = [];
        $params = [];

        foreach ($values as $id => $value) {
            $id = (int) $id;
            $cases[] = "WHEN {$id} then ?";
            $params[] = $value;
            $ids[] = $id;
        }

        $ids = implode(',', $ids);
        $cases = implode(' ', $cases);
        $params[] = Carbon::now();

        return \DB::update("UPDATE `{$table}` SET `value` = CASE `id` {$cases} END, `updated_at` = ? WHERE `id` in ({$ids})", $params);
    }
```

This apparently increase performance by 13x

2) As per another comment, another idea is to do it on a per record basis, but do the whole thing as a single transaction, which makes it much faster.

```
    DB::beginTransaction();

    // your loop and updates;

    if( !$user )
    {
    rollbackTransaction();
    } else {
    // Else commit the queries
    commitTransaction();
    }
```

3) There is a laravel library also that appears to try and solve this issue. https://github.com/mavinoo/laravelBatch

Note: I have not tried or tested any of the above solutions.

Answer (score 2):

I think the only way to do this without n queries would be to

- (optional) backup table
- grab the records and create an array with all the updated data
- bulk delete the records
- bulk insert from array

That's 3 queries.

Iterating through n records is not practical for my application either; I was hoping there was an alternative but it looks like I'm going to have to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

We can Insert and update batch (bulk) in laravel using this Package

- [Laravel Batch](https://github.com/mavinoo/laravelBatch)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution #1.** First of all you can use native [Laravel Upsert](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#upserts) for mass update:

```php
$payload = [
    ['id' => 1, 'value' => 'foo'],
    ['id' => 2, 'value' => 'bar'],
];
Setting::upsert($payload, ['id'], ['value']);
```

But this method has side effect as increase auto increment even if you update rows.
Current behavior happen because under the hood `upsert` create sql query: *INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE*.
This is the engine mechanism: before inserting, the next ID in the counter is searched for and updated. Then it tries to insert it into the table, and then updates it, but the ID counter is not rolled back. That's why this mechanism is good to use on primary key other than numbers or without autoincrement.
more detail about this issue: [ON DUPLICATE KEY + AUTO INCREMENT issue mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23516958/on-duplicate-key-auto-increment-issue-mysql)

**Solution #2**. Create Laravel macros for *Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder* only for mass update

Using example:

```php
$payload = [
    ['id' => 1, 'value' => 'foo'],
    ['id' => 2, 'value' => 'bar'],
];
Setting::bulkUpdate($payload, ['id'], ['value']);
```

Full sql query which was execute:

```sql
UPDATE `settings`
SET `value` =
    (CASE
        WHEN `id` = '1' THEN 'foo'
        WHEN `id` = '2' THEN 'bar'
     END),
    `description` =
    (CASE
        WHEN `id` = '1' THEN 'wow'
        WHEN `id` = '2' THEN 'cool'
    END)
WHERE `id` IN ('1', '2');
```

Register macros in app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use App\Macros\BulkUpdateMacros;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Builder::macro('bulkUpdate', function(array $values, $uniqueBy, array $updates) {
            return (new BulkUpdateMacros($this, $values, $uniqueBy, $updates))->handle();
        });
    }
}
```

Code of macros app/Macros/BulkUpdateMacros.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Macros;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class BulkUpdateMacros {
    /**
     * The base query builder instance.
     *
     * @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    protected $builder;

    /**
     * Set of rows.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $values;

    /**
     * Identify fields.
     *
     * @var string|array
     */
    protected $uniqueBy;

    /**
     * Create a new macros instance.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $builder
     * @param array $values
     * @param array $updates
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($builder, array $values, $uniqueBy, array $updates)
    {
        $this->builder = $builder;
        $this->values = $values;
        $this->updates = $updates;
        $this->uniqueBy = $uniqueBy;
    }

    /**
     * Compile raw sql query.
     *
     * @return string [sql query]
     */
    private function getSqlQuery(): string
    {
        $values = $this->values;
        $updates = $this->updates;
        $uniqueBy = $this->uniqueBy;
        if (!is_array(reset($values))) {
            $values = [$values];
        }
        if (!is_array($uniqueBy)) {
            $uniqueBy = [$uniqueBy];
        }
        $tableName = $this->builder->getModel()->getTable();

        // compile columns for raw sql
        $columns = collect($updates)->map(function($field) use ($values, $uniqueBy) {
            $cases = collect($values)->map(function($row) use ($field, $uniqueBy) {
                $conditions = collect($uniqueBy)->map(function($index) use ($row) {
                    return "`$index` = '$row[$index]'";
                })->implode(' AND ');
                $value = $row[$field];
                return "WHEN $conditions THEN '$value'";
            })->implode(' ');
            return "`$field` = (CASE $cases END)";
        })->implode(' ,');

        // compile where clause
        $where = collect($uniqueBy)->map(function($clause) use ($values) {
            $values = collect($values)->map(function($row) use ($clause) {
                return $row[$clause];
            })->implode("', '");
            return "`$clause` IN ('$values')";
        })->implode(' AND ');

        return "UPDATE `{$tableName}` SET {$columns} WHERE {$where}";
    }

    /**
     * Execute query for bulk update rows.
     *
     * @return int [total count of affected rows]
     */
    public function handle(): int
    {
        if (empty($this->values)) {
            return 0;
        }
        $connection = $this->builder->getQuery()->getConnection();
        return $connection->update($this->getSqlQuery());
    }
}
```

**Solution #3**. Package [LaravelBatch](https://github.com/mavinoo/laravelBatch)  which do the same as solution #2 but wrap in package. As for me its overhead but up to you.

Answer (score -3):

Please try the below code:

```
$data_to_be_updated = [ ['id'=>5,'name' => 'tarun'], ['id'=>6, 'name' => 'Akash'],
                        ['id'=>8, 'name' => 'Soniya'], ['id'=>9,'name' => 'Shalu']
                      ];
foreach ($data_to_be_updated as $key => $value) {
    $data = Model::where('id',$value['id'])->first();
    if ($data) {
        $data->name = $value['name'];
        $data->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: In your above example, there will executed 8 queries (4 queries for fetching record and 4 for saving updated data) . But i want to run only 1 query.

Comment: that is not batch query

Answer (score -3):

you can do it like this above mentioned:-

```
foreach($ids as $key => $id) {
    Model::where('id', $id)->update($updated_array[$key]);
}
```