# PDO avoid gaps when using ON DUPLICATE UPDATE

Tags: php, pdo

I'm using `pdo` to handle my database and I've just noticed that when I try to insert multiple rows if I use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` there is a gap in the auto-incremented field(in my case it is called `id`).

This is my table:

```
id  |  name  |  age 
1   |  Emma  |  20
2   |  Jane  |  21
3   |  John  |  25
```

And my statement is:

```
$pdo->prepare('
    INSERT INTO person 
        (`name`, `age`) 
    VALUES 
        (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
        age = VALUES(`age`)
')->execute(['Emma', '20', 'Jane', '21', 'Sarah', '35']);
```

If i run this query it will insert `name: Sarah`, `age: 35` with id `6`(a gap of `2` ids). Why is this happening? And is there a solution to that?

(p.s i want it to work with multiple rows insert)

Comment: Why do you care about continuity here? It's meaningless for all intents and purposes.

Comment: Is the `name` column a key? Show your `CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: `name` is UNIQUE @JonStirling

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23516958/on-duplicate-key-auto-increment-issue-mysql

Answer (score 0):

That's expected behaviour for `auto_increment` values. It increments the value every time you run an`INSERT` on it. Even if that insert fails because of a unique value already existing. So even though you have a `ON DUPLICATE KEY` value in your query, it still tries to `INSERT` them once before realising they are already in there.

If you want to work around this you could split your query into two parts where you first try to `SELECT` the users and then when you see they don't exist, you `INSERT` them. That way you don't try to `INSERT` any values that might already exist so you won't increment the `auto_increment` value.

EDIT: You can also play around with the auto increment lock mode. I'm not exactly sure how reliable this is, but you can find some information on it here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html

Comment: hey @DirkScholten, and how do i do that? X_X

Comment: Don't do a separate `SELECT`, `INSERT`, since that is prone to race condition problems. That's exactly what `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is there to avoid.

Comment: @emma The general idea would be that you have two pdo statements. `$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?');
$stmt->execute($email);
$user = $stmt->fetch();` You can then check `$user` to see if the user exists in the database. If it does then you run your update and if it doesn't you run an insert.

But like deceze said. This is not the safest way to do things. It could happen that you select a user and find that it doesn't exist, then just before you start your insert someone else inserts that user. That's why the way you do it now is much safer.