# Clean auto increment on primary key with multiple indexes

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I have a table that holds various users by `user_id` with many other indexed columns of ids from third-party tools they use.

For example, table `users`

```
user_id    |    user_name    |    zendesk_id    |    mailchimp_id   |    todoist_id
```

We have crons configured to hit these third parties for a list of users so that our db has any new users inserted. In the event of a `user_name` change on the third party, we also want to update that information on our side to keep in sync.

`user_id` is a primary key with auto-increment.
all third party service columns (ex. `zendesk_id`) are unique and indexed.

Per mysql documentation, auto-increment will not work properly when other columns are indexed (see similar, but not duplicate question explaining this: [ON DUPLICATE KEY + AUTO INCREMENT issue mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23516958/on-duplicate-key-auto-increment-issue-mysql) )

Since mysql has this documented problem, my question is this:

**How can I keep a reasonably clean auto-increment on `user_id` when I am pulling full user lists from these third parties to insert new users and update existing users?**

Comment: What's a "clean" auto-increment?

Comment: Reading the question you linked to, and also other questions it links to, I would guess you mean that you want your auto-increment values to be continuous (i.e. no missing values). **Don't.** Auto-increments are required to be unique, not continuous. Are you also going to renumber millions of primary keys if you delete a row? It's not worth it. Id's are not row numbers.

Comment: @billkarwin the goal is not perfect sequencing, the issue is that `on duplicate key update` increments 1 for each record. If I run a cron once a day for 5 third-parties, each third-party containing 250 records... that means my AI goes up 1,250 per day. And that might only generate 2-5 new users in the db. Eventually that number gets too big, and for no reason at all.

Comment: So your primary key is going to reach the maximum integer in 1.7 million days?