# Eloquent query doesn't select a specific ID

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

This question is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23516958/on-duplicate-key-auto-increment-issue-mysql)

I haven't changed the default `autoIncrement` from the table migration, however I noticed i couldn't get a model from the `ID` for a specific row. For the other rows it works fine. I cleared cache thinking it was a cache issue, but seems it is not.

Behaviour

I got records `1,..., 58, 59, 60`

When i select a model

```php
$object = Post::find(59);
// $object returns null but record exists
```

However i added another record via the app to check if the behaviour is the same, and the record from `60` is not null and it is the expected behaviour. Has anyone encountered this? If so what would be the best approach to overcome this.

I am using XAMPP v8.0.8 on Windows

Edit:
Post Model

```php
class Post extends Model
{
    use HasFactory,Searchable,SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = [
        'hash_id','user_id','location','subjects','request_type'
    ]; 

    protected $casts = [
        'location' => 'array',
        'subjects' => 'array'        
    ];
    
    public function User()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
    }

    public function searchableAs()
    {
        return 'posts';
    }    
   
}
```

Migration file

```php
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('hash_id')->unique();
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->json('location');            
            $table->json('subjects');
            $table->string('request_type');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you update your question with your Post model and database table structure please?

Comment: @toyi, just updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming from soft deletes this happens if the record is deleted. Try looking in the deleted_at field on database.

Comment: Oh my..  I had deleted the record but have missed to check the `deleted_at`. Thank you for the catch.